# jQuery Ratyの評価をsubmitボタンでPHPに渡す方法

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

jQuery Raty(http://wbotelhos.com/raty) を使用して、書籍のレビューを投稿するフォームに5段階評価をつけたいと思っています。

```
<form action="review.php" method="post">
  <label class="control-label" for="title">作品名</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
  <label class="control-label" for="author">作者名</label>
  <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="form-control">
  <label class="control-label" for="review">感想・意見</label>
  <textarea name="review" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
  <label class="control-label" for="star">評価（5段階）</label>
  <div id="star"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.raty.defaults.path = "./images";
    $('#star').raty();
  </script>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="送信する">
</div>
```

このとき、review.phpで$_POST['author']などと同様に投票された値を取得して、mysqli_queryなどでその値をDBに格納したいのです。

調べてみたところ、JavascriptのonclickでPHPにデータを渡す方法はあったものの、フォームのsubmitを利用してデータを渡す方法はありませんでした。

先日初めてPHPとMySQLをさわり（jQueryもほとんど経験の無い）初心者なので至らないところも多々あると存じますが何卒ご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

http://wbotelhos.com/raty には target の項目があります。
★が選択されたときに、input の value を変更する事ができるようです。

```
<input id="hint" type="text" />
```

この type を hidden にすれば、form の submit 時に、データが渡されるようになると考えます。

```
<input id="hint" type="hidden" />
```